# I have to create a view with following attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

Create a view  named customer_mobile_details which has the following attributes. Display customer id,customer name,mobile number, sales id, net amount,model name and manufacturer name of the mobiles, they have purchased. Sort the records based on customer id,customer name,sales id in ascending order.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GxS.jpg)

My code is as below.

```
create view customer_mobile_details 
as( select Customer_Info.Customer_ID, Customer_Info.Customer_Name, 
Distributor.Mobilenumber,
Sales_Info.Salesid, Sales_Info.Net_Amount,
Mobile_Master.Model_Name, Mobile_Master.Manufacturer
from Customer_Info
inner join Sales_Info
on Customer_Info.Customer_ID = Sales_Info.Customer_ID
inner join Mobile_Master
on Sales_Info.Price = Mobile_Master.Price
inner join Distributor
on Mobile_Master.Distributor_ID = Distributor.Distributor_ID)
order by Customer_Info.Customer_ID, Customer_Info.Customer_Name, Sales_Info.Salesid asc;
```

But i'm getting some error. It says
Failed Test
Test Case 2: Check the attribute name,constraints,sorting etc.

Can someone help me to figure it out where I made the mistake?

Comment: "Failed Test Test Case 2" is not an Oracle error message.  is this code being checked by some kind of teaching tool?

Comment: Yes. There are 2 test cases. Test case 1 has been executed successfully. But I got this error in test case 2.

Comment: is this join right 'INNER JOIN Mobile_Master ON Sales_Info.Price = Mobile_Master.Price' ?  shouldnt this join be using IME_NO ?

Comment: Sir, I've executed the code using IME_NO. But still got the same error.  Where I made the mistake?

Comment: The `order by` in a view -- if allowed -- is superfluous and generally ignored.  In fact, the syntax looks off because of the parentheses.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because teaching tools often have idiosyncratic, wrong-headed or even just plain wrong criteria. We can make all sorts of guesses about what the test writer is expecting but we cannot actually give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try this one. Works for me.
This is pretty self explanatory.
```

```
create view customer_mobile_details as 
(select customer_id,
customer_info.customer_name,
customer_info.mobile,
sales_info.salesid,
sales_info.net_amount,
mobile_master.model_name,
mobile_master.manufacturer
from customer_info
join sales_info using(customer_id)
join mobile_master using(ime_no))

order by customer_id,
customer_info.customer_name,
sales_info.salesid;
```

Comment: It is nice to point what was the issue with the query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually in the question as the mobile number to be taken is the attribute named "Mobile" from the table 'Customer_info' and not the "mobilenumber" attribute from table 'Distributor'.